# Access json data with Laravel and Inertia

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, inertiajs

I have a simple form with 1 input field and a submit button.

All that does is get the user input, match it with an external API, and submit both records to the database.

The response from the external API is JSON format, like this but I only want to retrieve the `text` field under `choices`

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "object": "tc",
  "created": 1655642237,
  "model": "text-code",
  "choices": [
    {
      "text": "paragraph text here",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "finish_reason": "length"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is stored in a variable `$complete` so when I access it in the view, I get all of this with no way to target specific elements only.

This is my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $prompts = Writer::all();

        return Inertia::render('Writer', [
            'prompts' => $prompts
        ]);
}

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $complete = $start->complete([
             'engine' => '002',
             'prompt' => $request->input('inputText')
        ]);

        $data = json_decode($complete, true);

        Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'inputText' => 'required|min:5|max:255|string',
        ])->validate();

        Writer::create([
            'request' => $request->input('inputText'),
            'response' => $data['choices']
        ]);

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'success.');

}
```

I have to pass `$complete` to the `create()` method because passing `$data` gives an error

> Array to string conversion

and

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

However if I `return $data['choices']` right after the variable, I get the fields that are only under `choices`

The view is pretty simple

```
<div class="card w-100 bg-light mt-4 mb-4" v-for="prompt in $page.props.prompts">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ prompt.request }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ prompt.response }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm not sure if this is exactly your problem, but have you tried {{ complete.choices[0].text }} ?

Comment: I am not returning `$complete` to the view, I'm returning `$prompts` in the `index()` method. But in any case, trying `{{ prompt.response.choices[0].text }}` returns a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to acces the data in the `$choices`-array (it's an array, not a string, and that's why you got an error accordingly), change the corresponding lines in your `store`-method to

```
Writer::create([
    'request' => $request->input('inputText'),
    'response' => $data['choices'][0]['text']
]);
```

But be aware that `$data[ 'choices' ]` could be empty, so before storing any value, make sure to check for existence and provide a default value, e.g.

```
$text = $data['choices'][0]['text'] ?? 'my-default-value';
```